# Soft Keyboard not getting displayed

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to display a soft keyboard when the EditText is selected. I tried this bit of code in the onclick event handler of EditText as follows:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(txtUserId, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

But this did not worked :(

Please help with all the steps needed for getting the soft keyboard displayed when the EditText is clicked.

Regards,

Comment: I don't understand... isn't this the default behavior of an `EditText`?

Comment: When you click on your `EditText` the keyboard don't appears?

Comment: hi, i am not sure if "soft keyboard" is the exact term for this or not. i want to refer the keyboard which appears from the bottom of the screen when we want to provide some inputs to an EditText. When the user clicks the EditText to provide some input, then i want that keyboard to appear. Do i need to write code from scratch for this or there is something in-built? Please suggest